# Is it possible to inject Spring configuration method ?

Tags: java, spring

With Spring Configuration class i.e without using XML based configurations. Is it possible to Inject the factory method like in Guice ?

In Guice if I had a provider method like

```
  @Provides
      public DatastoreService datastoreService(String url) { // Spring will inject this method parameter, if it is mapped of course. 
        return DatastoreServiceFactory(url);
      }
```

Is this possible with Spring ?

Like

```
@Bean
public Performer poeticDuke(Poem poem) {
return new PoeticJuggler(poem);
}
```

rather than:

```
@Bean
public Performer poeticDuke() {
return new PoeticJuggler(sonnet29());
}
```

This is from the book [Spring in Action 3](http://www.manning.com/walls4/)

Comment: You can use `@Autowired` and `@Value` on the method (arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure it is possible if `Poem` is bean too. Otherwise it seems strange: where can Spring find `Poem` otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will work as long as the argument to the method is also a Spring bean!

Check out one of the many examples used in Spring Boot like [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/social/FacebookAutoConfiguration.java), [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration.java) or [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java)

Comment: Pleased to know that.